# LTspice can't find definition of model "R"

Tags: ltspice

[image: the circuit that I am trying to analyse]

I get these errors:

```
Questionable use of curly braces in "r1 n001 out {5k-r}"
    Error: undefined symbol in: "5k-[r]"

Questionable use of curly braces in "r2 out 0 {r}"
    Error: undefined symbol in: "[r]"

Circuit: * C:\******\Draft2.asc

Error on line 3 : r1 n001 out (5k-r)
     Unknown parameter "-r"

Error on line 4 : r2 out 0 (r)
     Unable to find definition of model "r"

Fatal Error: Missing resistance value for "R2"
```

I tried removing the curly brackets but the result was the same. How should I fix this?

Comment: Works for me. Can you post contents of the .asc file as code?

Comment: Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 240 -16 48 -16
WIRE 240 16 240 -16
WIRE 48 80 48 -16
WIRE 240 112 240 96
WIRE 416 112 240 112
WIRE 240 128 240 112
WIRE 48 192 48 160
WIRE 240 224 240 208
FLAG 48 192 0
FLAG 240 224 0
FLAG 416 112 out
IOPIN 416 112 Out
SYMBOL voltage 48 64 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL res 224 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value {5k-R}
SYMBOL res 224 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value {R}
TEXT 336 208 Left 2 ;.step param R 1k 5k 1k
TEXT 344 232 Left 2 !.op

Comment: Maybe you're talking about this* C:\Users\......\Draft5.asc
V1 N001 0 5
R1 N001 out {5k-R}
R2 out 0 {R}
* .step param R 1k 5k 1k
.op
.backanno
.end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:-

```
TEXT 336 208 Left 2 ;.step param R 1k 5k 1k TEXT 344 232 Left 2
```

That `;` before `.step` means you entered the text as a comment, not a SPICE directive. As a result the simulator is ignoring it.

To fix it, right-click on the `.step param R 1k 5k 1k` text in the schematic, then in the dialog that comes up click on the 'SPICE directive' radio button.

[image]

Comment: Feel free to add my image from the comments in the other answer.  Visual aid might make it more clear for future users who stumble across the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

It should work, though you should use something like {5.000001k - R} otherwise it will complain about the value being zero. Perhaps it is possible you have some character other than 'R' in one place or another (such as 'Ɍ')

It is not matching the R in your .step directive with the R in your resistor values.

See below (mixed case deliberately used to show it doesn't matter):

[image]

Comment: I made the same circuit that you made but I am still getting the same error.Questionable use of curly braces in "r1 n001 out {5.000001k-r}"
    Error: undefined symbol in: "5.000001k-[r]"
Questionable use of curly braces in "r2 out 0 {r}"
    Error: undefined symbol in: "[r]"
Circuit: * C:\Users\......\Draft2.asc

Error on line 3 : r1 n001 out (5.000001k-r)
  Unknown parameter "-r"
Error on line 4 : r2 out 0 (r)
  Unable to find definition of model "r"
Fatal Error: Missing resistance value for "R2"

Comment: I would try remaking it from scratch. I can get the same error by changing (say) an R to an X, so either you have an oddball character or something else is screwy.

Comment: I can duplicate his errors exactly if I turn the `.step` command from a SPICE directive into a comment.  Maybe he accidentally made it a comment and his color profile uses black for both text comments and SPICE directives???

Comment: @kauselis3000  Make sure you have this button selected for your `.step` command.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eXNo.png

Comment: Yes, it was comment and now it works after I changed it to a SPICE directive. I will be more careful next time.